Button colors don't take color scheme defined in manifest into consideration anymore
I have a Google Workspace Add-on for Gmail using Google Apps Script. that has been deployed for more than 1 year now. I've decided to put a log in some part of it and changed a string and when I redeployed it the color scheme became buggy. Text in TextButtonStyle. FILLED buttons became dark and the background color is set to the default one instead of the one in the manifest.

In this image, the two buttons are defined like so:
const button1 = CardService.newTextButton()
    .setTextButtonStyle(CardService.TextButtonStyle.FILLED)
    .setText("Button1")
    .setOnClickAction(CardService.newAction().
      setFunctionName("button1Menu"));

const button2 = CardService.newTextButton()
    .setTextButtonStyle(CardService.TextButtonStyle.FILLED)
    .setBackgroundColor("#FF5733")
    .setText("Button2")
    .setOnClickAction(CardService.newAction().
      setFunctionName("button2Menu"));

And here is the addsOn part of the manifest:
{
  "common": {
    "name": "Test App",
    "layoutProperties": {
      "primaryColor": "#FF5733"
    },
    "logoUrl": "MY_LOGO_URL"
  },
  "gmail": {
    "version": "TRUSTED_TESTER_V2",
    "contextualTriggers": [
      {
        "unconditional": {},
        "onTriggerFunction": "featurePage"
      }
    ]
  }
}

So it is working when I set the background color explicitly. And the header of the application is actually using the color in the manifest, but the buttons are not.
I've tried removing the changed code, changing the place of primaryColor and secondaryColor in the manifest because they used to be in the the gmail field but in the documentation, it is written that it should be under common.layoutProperties. I have also tried removing the version attribute under gmail. The only thing that has been working so far has been setting the color of the buttons manually in the code so for now, I'm doing that.

If something was working in undocumented ways in Google Apps Script, then it could stop working at any time without previous notice. This has happened before.
If you are sure that this issue is a bug, then please take a look at the Google Apps Script Issue Tracker. If it still needs to be reported, create a new issue. Please look at How to get help for details.
On the other hand, changes to things that are documented usually are announced in advance in Google Workspace Updates among other places and documented in the Release Notes.
So please make sure you follow the syntax and schemes according to the official documentation, and if you decide to deviate from them, please make sure to document it so you can quickly identify the cause of the issue when it stops working. For this, you might use JSDoc and the Google Apps Script API or a tool that uses it like Google Apps Scripts GitHub Assitant, a popular extension for Google Chrome, i.e., to sync your project to a Git repo or CLASP to sync the project to a local storage device to include documentation using tools and files that are not supported by the Google Apps Script online IDE.

There has been a change in the TextButtonStyle code. I used to have  CardService.TextButtonStyle.TEXT in my code which now fails (it came from the cardbuilder, so not entirely undocumented, just brutaly removed without warning!).
It would be nice if clasp could show deprecated code...
